# How can I highlight certain words in minted with different colors?

Tags: beamer, listings, minted

I would like to highlight some specific words inside the `minted` environment when using `beamer`.

```
 \documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minted}[mathescape,
           gobble=2,
           linenos,
           fontsize=\tiny,
           framesep=2mm]{ocaml}
  let process il =
    let module IV = Instr_visitor in
    let visit i t = instrument i t in
    IV.map_instr IU.is_mem_write visit il
    |> insert_instr_list BEFORE !il_update
\end{minted}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For example, for the code below, I would like to highlight the `visit` at line four and three using red color. I know the solution in `lstlisting`, but still, I cannot find a solution towards `minted` environment, could anyone help me on that? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I haven’t tested it but could you adapt http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298554/42?