# How to highlight (color/draw attention to) a particular snippet in Minted

Tags: minted, sourcecode

I'm currently doing some work on error messages in programming languages. As such, I'm showing faulty pieces of code, alongside the compiler-errors accompanying them.

I'm using minted for the code snippets, but ideally, in addition to normal syntax highlighting, I'd like to highlight the sections of the code at which the error is located, by underlining them, putting a red box around them, shading their background, etc.

Is this possible using Minted?

Comment: Closely related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297875/42.

Comment: Thanks, I initially dismissed it because I thought it was about highlighting specific words automatically, but it turns out the solution was in there.

Comment: See also [highlighting - How to highlight a portion of Matlab Code - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446078/how-to-highlight-a-portion-of-matlab-code) for some other options.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The minted documentation has an example using `escapeinside`. I’m just copying it here:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
def f(x):
    y = x|\colorbox{green}{**}|2
    return y
\end{minted}
```

Highlights as

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Color boxes start with a small but noticeable space, which can be annoying when highlighting whole lines of Python where indentation matters. The command `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` prevents this.

Comment: The `||` did not work for me, giving some "File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine" error that I couldn't easily resolve. Using `[someoptions,escapeinside=@@]` instead worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

You can highlight certain lines with `highlightlines={1,2-3,5-10}`, e.g.

[image: Screenshot of rendered code showing highlighted lines]

```
\begin{minted}[highlightlines={1,3-4,6-10}]{python}
def f(x):
    y = x ** 2
    return y

def f(x):
    y = x ** 2
    return y

def f(x):
    y = x ** 2
    return y
\end{minted}
```

You can change the color by using, say, `highlightcolor=red`. In general, quoting from the minted package documentation:

> `highlightcolor`: Set the color used for highlightlines, using a predeﬁned color name from color or xcolor, or a color deﬁned via `\definecolor`

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: Can this be used to highlight two lines in different colors?

Comment: @Eric I had a quick look at minted's documentation and it doesn't seem to be possible.