# How to highlight lines on a pattern using minted?

Tags: minted, highlighting, l3regex

The Answer in ["How to highlight (color/draw attention to) a particular snippet in Minted"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298383/how-to-highlight-color-draw-attention-to-a-particular-snippet-in-minted) is very helpful. But, is there a way to highlight lines in minted on a pattern?
E.g. not to say "`highlightlines={1,2-3,5-10}`", but say somthing like "**`highlightlinesregex={/def .*:/}`**"

Thanks for your ideas in advance

Thomas